# What procs does linux kill on OOM?

Tags: kernel

When a machine runs out of memory is there a rule on what processes Linux kills?

Does it kill the process taking the most memory? Or the latest or so?

Comment: Re "*When a machine runs out of memory*" ... It's not only that. There are situations where OOM is called/invoked even if system memory hasn't reached its limit ... One example is when a [cgroup](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/cgroup-v1/memory.txt) tries to exceed it's maximum hard memory limit set.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is some [information on kernel.org](https://www.kernel.org/doc/gorman/html/understand/understand016.html) about how OOM selects a process to kill (from Mel Gorman's book "Understanding the Linux Virtual Memory Manager"): *(please note that this information is from the time of Linux kernel 2.6)*

> ##### 13.3  Selecting a Process
>
> The function `select_bad_process()` is responsible for choosing a
> process to kill. It decides by stepping through each running task and
> calculating how suitable it is for killing with the function
> `badness()`. The badness is calculated as follows, note that the square
> roots are integer approximations calculated with `int_sqrt()`;
>
> ```
> badness_for_task = total_vm_for_task / (sqrt(cpu_time_in_seconds) * sqrt(sqrt(cpu_time_in_minutes)))
> ```
>
> This has been chosen to select a process that is using a large amount
> of memory but is not that long lived. Processes which have been
> running a long time are unlikely to be the cause of memory shortage so
> this calculation is likely to select a process that uses a lot of
> memory but has not been running long. If the process is a root process
> or has `CAP_SYS_ADMIN` capabilities, the points are divided by four as
> it is assumed that root privilege processes are well behaved.
> Similarly, if it has `CAP_SYS_RAWIO` capabilities (access to raw
> devices) privileges, the points are further divided by 4 as it is
> undesirable to kill a process that has direct access to hardware.

So to sum up: OOM selects a process, that fits the criteria of using a large amount of memory but is not that long lived. In additon, if the process runs as `root` (or otherwise has admin privileges), it is 4 times less likely to be killed.

That's about it.